# Entity Framework Core 2 default DbContextOptions

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

Is it possible to have some default DbContextOptions that are overwritten by the constructor? According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext this is how it works.

> If both are used, OnConfiguring is applied last and can overwrite
>   options supplied to the constructor argument.

I am imagine that if I do like this

```
MyContext myContext = new MyContext();
```

Is would use the default context. This works fine with using this

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{    
    optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("host=localhost;port=5432;database=mycontext;user id=postgres;password=*******");
}
```

But the annoying thing is that if I use

```
 MyContext myContext = new MyContext(someOtherOptions);
```

someOtherOptions will be overridden by the on configuring. Seem like it should have been the other way around

Comment: Can you explain more the use case? By default context do you mean using parameterless constructor? And where would you like to *overwrite options for testing* - in `OnConfiguring`? Or initialize defaults in `OnConfiguring`?

Comment: Added more explanation. Let me know if it is still unclear

Comment: Thanks, now it's crystal clear. See the linked duplicate, especially the `if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured))` part of my answer.